# Vector resizing shortcut?

Tags: c++, vector

Can `std::vector foo.resize(foo.size()+1);` be turned into `foo.size++;`? I know vectors auto-resize, but it would be a handy shortcut.

Comment: No, `size()` is read-only.

Comment: No it cannot.  And frequent manual resizes like that will hurt performance; you should rely on the default resizing behavior.

Comment: I beat that you doing something wrong. Manual resizing can be used to speed up code, but this is a rare operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't.

You have no access to the size of a vector other than by:

- its functions that perform data-based operations such as adding a new element
- its function `size()` that returns, in a read-only manner, its current size.

The way to spell `foo.size++` is `foo.emplace_back()`. You do this because you want a new element, not because you want the vector to be a bit bigger. These desires are two fundamentally, if very subtly, different things.

Comment: Technically you could achieve this by wrapping `vector` in your own type, and giving it a `size` data member of a proxy type that implements `operator++` .... but please don't.

Comment: THAT. I want to manually increase, or decrease `operator--`, so why not?

Comment: @KelsonRumak Because that would be creating an inappropriate and unfamiliar interface for a completely conventional, idiomatic and entirely standard data type, for absolutely no concrete gain whatsoever. It's also error-prone to inherit standard containers in many cases. I gave a hint as to how you _could_ go about it, because I'm kind and you are free to play around with things ... but I won't put an example in the answer because I don't want you to encourage you to do this in production code.

Comment: Changed my order a bit and got `foo.emplace_back()` to work, thanks @Asteroids. I still want that ++ to work, but that's another day.

Comment: `Foo& operator++(Foo &f, int) {f.downFoo.resize(f.downFoo.size()+1); return f;}`

Comment: Yes, pretty much.